# If Input is focused trigger X else trigger Y

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, input

I'm trying to trigger an opacity animation on a menu when the search input is focused, and when it is not focused for that menu to return to opacity:1.

My botched code below.

```
if($('input#edit-keys-2').is(":focus")){
  $('#zone-header ul#nice-menu-1').animate({opacity:0}, 300);
}else{
  $('#zone-header ul#nice-menu-1').animate({opacity:1}, 300);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.focus()](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) and [.blur()](https://api.jquery.com/blur/) like this instead

```
$('input#edit-keys-2').on("focus", function(){
  $('#zone-header ul#nice-menu-1').animate({opacity:0}, 300);
}).on("blur", function(){
  $('#zone-header ul#nice-menu-1').animate({opacity:1}, 300);
});
```

```js
$('input#edit-keys-2').on("focus", function(){
  $('#nice-menu-1').animate({opacity:0}, 300);
}).on("blur", function(){
  $('#nice-menu-1').animate({opacity:1}, 300);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="focus me" id="edit-keys-2"/>
<div id="nice-menu-1">animate me</div>
```

Comment: because a *blur* event is fired when an input loses focus.  Check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur. But using `.on()` you are listening to those events (attaching event handlers)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use the JQuery events:

```
.on( "blur", handler )
.on( "focus", handler )
```

https://api.jquery.com/blur/ 
https://api.jquery.com/focus/